# I'm trying to create a small program that orders people based on how much they donate. But I'm not sure how a databse works

Tags: python, python-3.x, database

So I have a list of people that donate to charity. But I'm not sure how to sort those people out in descending order.
It starts like this:

```
    average_donation = int()
    number_of_donations = int()
    rating_of_donations = (average_donation/number_of_donations)
    rating_good = rating_of_donations > 3
    rating_average = rating_of_donations => 1 and < 3
    rating_bad = rating_of_donations =< 0
    
    Name1 = [rating_of_donations (rating of that person), average_donation (that person's average donation)
    Name2...

...
```

Then it should print out a list of people in descending order (from best rating to worst).
Though I'm not sure how to assign each person different values for the same variable, so I suppose a database is involved.
Does anyone know how to do it? Thanks

P.S.
I'm very new to python

Comment: Hi, how does your input data look like?

Comment: What did you tried? Can you provide a [example]?